# Designing a media server application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, flex4

I'm looking into designing a media server application for a school project and was wondering what the best way to go about it would be. It's going to be n-tiered with the logic tier taking care of all the indexing, user authentication, file storage and the rest.

Here are the options I've come up with so far...

- Java back-end, Adobe Flex front-end
- WCF service back-end, ASP.NET front-end
- C# back-end, Silverlight front-end

I'm not sure if I'm going along the right path for a media server application. Do any of the options listed above seem fine or should I be looking into another technology?

Comment: Something that ought to be clarified, here: C# and Java are programming languages. WCF is a communications framework. Choosing between C#/Java likely depends on which language you are most comfortable with. Choosing between back-end communication technologies is a different consideration. A Silverlight front-end, for example, will probably still require the use of backing services...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all seem fine, but it really depends on what you intend it to do. The WCF solution would give you the most flexibility, as you could write a bunch of services to do all the work, then write a lightweight front end to interact with the services. This would then give you scope to move the front-end to different machine, or even create other UI's, such as mobile apps (iOS/Andriod/WM7) which only need to interact with your services.